# extend session time out for asp.net (step by step!!)

Tags: asp.net

I am using session value to identify the language that user chosen. 
LoadMultilingual() is the method that I will call for all pages to assign the value for label.
I realized that the session value wont store value for long time, by default it store 20 minutes, so when user click any button that will reload the multilingual function, it will prompt an error.

I set the time out for session value for 60 minutes, when I try to click a button at around 45 minutes, it throw me this value.

the code below is how I declare the timeout for session

```
<sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="60" />
```

The code below is the code form C# that user choose their preferred language at Login page..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["index"] = null;
            Session["counter"] = null;
            Session["LoginMsg"] = null;

            if (Session["Lang"] == null)
            {
                Session["Lang"] = Request.UserLanguages[0];
            }

            if (Session["login"] == null)
            {
                Session["login"] = 1;
            }
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadMultilingual();

                if ((String)Session["Lang"] == "zh-TW")
                {
                    ddLang.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddLang.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            Session["stop"] = null;



        }

protected void ddLang_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Lang"] = ddLang.SelectedValue;

            LoadMultilingual();

        }
```

The code below is the code from C# that use session for multilingual.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
                DisableLinkBtn();
                LoadMultilingual(); 
            }  

        }

 private void LoadMultilingual()
        { 
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Lang"].ToString());
                rm = new ResourceManager("SOMaintenance.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

                Site1 site = this.Master as Site1;
                if (site != null)
                {
                    Label SensorTemperatureLabel = site.FindControl("label1") as Label;
                    string header = validate.getError("userheader", (String)Session["Lang"]);
                    SensorTemperatureLabel.Text = header;
                }


                if ((String)Session["Lang"] == "zh-TW")
                {
                    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "用户账号";
                    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "用户名称";
                    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "用户职位";
                }

                btnAdd.Attributes.Add("title", rm.GetString("btnAdd", ci));
                btnSearch.Attributes.Add("title", rm.GetString("btnSearch", ci)); 

        }
```

Anyone has any idea why it is not working? my code work perfectly find within 40 minutes, the things is I already set the session timeout for 60 minutes.
The error is pointing to session["Lang"] this value. (its only appear around 45 minutes and after, I tried on 25minutes it's ok)

Comment: Did you try following the directions to see the underlying reason for the error? We can't tell you what's wrong until you do that.

Comment: @mason not really.. do you mind show me how to do it?

Comment: **Read** the error message. It tells you what to do. If you get stuck on it, then explain what part you don't understand.

Comment: @mason I do check my web.config, but there is nothing as the error show, it is mean I need to add into my web.config?

Comment: Please *read* the error message. It specifically says "to enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a tag within the 'web.config' configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This tag should then have its 'mode' attribute set to off". It even gives you an example of what it should look like below that.

Comment: I already added 
     <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors> into my web config, but it thwo me object reference not set to an instance of an object... does it related to my session value? because I am doing multilingual by checking the session value.. the things is I already set the session value store up to 60 minutes. any idea?

Comment: Great, now you can see the actual error details. It's time to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to include the relevant code, the error message, and any other details necessary in the question, not as comments.

Comment: @mason done! appreciate your help! if you know any thing for my updated question, you are welcome to comment agian! :)

Comment: You still need to add the relevant code to your question. Reread my previous comment, there's a link to how to create an MCVE. You've gotta learn how to make an MCVE if you want to use Stack Overflow effectively.

Comment: @Mason added.. sorry, i missed it out

Answer (score 0):

If someone visits the page before you've initialize `Session["Lang"]` then they'll get a null reference exception. So you need to initialize it. The best place to do that is in the Session_Start event in your global application class (global.asax).

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Lang"] = //add your code here to figure out the language
}
```

By initializing it in the session start, you can ensure the variable will always be initialized (unless you later set it to null).

Also, you have cookieless authentication enabled. Do not do that! That's very insecure, as sensitive data will now be stored in the URL..

Comment: I do set it on the log in page, every seems fine until I leave the system for around 40 miniutes.. then only will have the error. I wonder why even I set the timeout for session at web.config but it is not working. for my understanding session value only will hold for 20 by default, why since I set it, it still will gone?

Answer (score 0):

After tested all the method for THREE days. I have found out the solution. 
For those which to extend Session in asp.net can use this method.

**Step 1 - set session time out at web.config**

Copy and paste the code below to web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>
   <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="60" />
```

Please take note, by default session value only last for **20 minutes**, as code above, I have set it to **60 minutes**.

**Step 2 - configuration IIS**

If you publish your web application to IIS, go to IIS Manager.

**Start --> IIS Manager --> Sites --> Default Web site** **--> ASP**
(If you didnt create a new one for your web app, else just click on the one you use for your web app)

then find **Session Properties --> time-out** set it to **01:00:00** it means 60 minutes.

By default you should see 00:20:00

After that click **Apply** on your right hand side.
Sample screen as below

[image]

After you done the step above, u can laugh your web application, then problem SOLVED!!!

Have a nice day and hope it help!